# Cloned Datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I duplicated the following fields. And my problem is the cloned datepicker isn't working.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <button type="button" id="childField" class="btn btn-primary btn-addon m-b-sm btn-rounded"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> ADD FIELDS</button>
</div>
<div id="Children">
  <div class="divider col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-7">
    <label for="child">Name of Child</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="child[]" id="child" placeholder="FULL NAME">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="ch_DateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" name="ch_DateOfBirth" id="DateOfBirth" placeholder="Date of Birth">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery for duplicating the fields.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#childField').click(function() {
        $('#Children').clone().insertAfter("#Children");
    });
});
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: I mean, the datepicker doesn't show up when the input field is clicked, anyways, I already find an answer. Thanks.

Comment: In the future, "it's not working" questions should include three things: (a) what you expect it to do, (b) why you think it should be doing this, and (c) what it is actually doing.

Comment: Yes I will. Thanks.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could fix that for _this_ question, not just the next one. This question is likely to close until it is improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clone some html it's loose it's event bindings so you have to reinitialise the events in that case date-pickers uses it's own event bindings.

And you also can't use multiple same ids so you have to change ids.

```js
var idInc = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#childField').click(function() {
    var cloned = $('#Children').clone();
    cloned.find('input').each(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).attr('id', id + '-' + idInc);
    })
    idInc++;
    cloned.insertAfter("#Children");
    $('.date-picker').datePicker() // Whatever // You have to reinitialise
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <button type="button" id="childField" class="btn btn-primary btn-addon m-b-sm btn-rounded"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> ADD FIELDS</button>
</div>
<div id="Children">
  <div class="divider col-md-12"></div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-7">
    <label for="child">Name of Child</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="child[]" id="child" placeholder="FULL NAME">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="ch_DateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" name="ch_DateOfBirth" id="DateOfBirth" placeholder="Date of Birth">
  </div>
</div>
```